# jsTree : Unresponsive while searching for large tree

Tags: jstree, jstree-search

I'm using `jsTree V3.0.0`. I've jsTree with 31000 nodes. When I make a search which have result of 500 nodes, my jsTree takes very long time to load. Even sometimes it crashes my browser. Please give any suggestion how to handle larger trees.